# Read to array from table in text file, while skipping specific column

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, file-io

I am trying to read the contents of a text file into 2D array in C++. The file contains 125 rows with 21 columns of integers (a table of integers). I'm to read this into an array that is 125 rows of **20** columns, *skipping column 21* of the file.

I defined the size of the array with variables, but *it just reads column 21 into the next row*, ignoring the new line. I need it to start each row in the array at the start of the new line from the file but ignore the last item in the table.

I'm not sure if I'm looking for it to skip column 21, or if I'm looking for it to start reading each column at a new line (or both?)

Text file looks like (is this called a matrix?) and it's number separated by 1 space and \n at end.
(The text file was generated by a program to generate rows of 20 numbers and the sum.)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 93
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 93
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 93
" etc
```

Other solutions I've found can be difficult for me to understand because people write their variables and functions non-descriptively. Some solutions require advanced methods I'm not supposed to use as well, such as vectors and string manipulation. I have currently learned everything before "pointers" so I can only use solutions I've learned in class. I've learned functions, arrays, search/sort, and basics like operators, loops, variables, etc. I'm not supposed to use vectors for this or string manipulation.

I will (eventually) have to sum the numbers in the array (after I extract the first 20 of each row from the file) so to compare the sum from the array final column to the last integer in each row of the file (which is a sum).

My function is (note: We are using namespace std)

```
void readArray() {

    ifstream infile("tableofintegers.txt");

    for (int rowcount = 0; rowcount < ROWS; rowcount++) // row loop
    {
        for (int colcount = 0; colcount < COLS; colcount++) // column loop
        {
            infile >> twoDArray[rowcount][colcount];  // read to array
        }

    }
}
```

These are variables:

```
const int ROWS = 125;
const int COLS = 20;
```

I tried this but got a runtime error

```
    file >> array[row][col];
            file.ignore(10, '\n');
```

The error when I tried file.ignore

> C:\path\matrix.exe (process 27316) exited with code -2147483645.

Not only is there an error, but it still "wraps" the read starting line two with the sum (last digit) of line 1.) As you can imagine, as this iterates, it keeps pushing the data over further and further.

I expected for the program to stop reading when it reached the limit of the array columns (20) then continue at the next line, but it didn't. My brain tells me something's not logical about that expectation, yet I have a dissonance or something going on. I can't really wrap my head around it. I also tried file.ignore which I expected would ignore 10 characters after the 20th column up to new line, but it just kicked an error and still wrapped.

Note: I'm printing the array to the console. Here is my code for that.

```
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
    {
    cout << setw(5) << dataArray[row][col];
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: "... then continue at the next line" - you did nothing to make that happen, so... it didn't. There are several ways to address this. You could read the data line by line as a string, populating a `std::istringstream` each superior iteration and just use that to enumerate your columns.  Or, if 'brittle' is on the menu, you could read your 20 values, *then* force the ignore-to-newline-or-EOF scenario. Either would probably work for your case. I'd choose the former, btw.

Comment: Thank you. I thought file.ignore would, or that limiting the size of the array would; so I thought I was doing "something" to make it happen. If I used istringstream, would I then have to turn it into integers in order to work math with the data? Is istringstream the usual method by which I would be able to do other manipulations of this data? (i.e. first 3, last 3, 2nd line, etc.) I would think forcing ignore would be more basic, as I've not gone far isn't the course yet- it may be what the teacher is looking for. But then would that method be able to do other extractions? The former probably

Comment: `file.ignore(10, '\n');` as you've shown it, after reading a single element, will do nothing but skip the rest of the line. At-most each row would give one read-element (the first one). The rest would be thrown out and the prior content in all of those slots would be retained. The fact is, per-line data should be processed exactly that way: *per line*. A string stream makes it easy, since you already know  you have the superior 'thing' (i.e. the line). Then all you have to do is use formatted extraction out of a string stream, using that line as the stream content, to pull you data.

Comment: You are in a good track, just try to break the problem in smaller problems and solve each of these. For example, write a function that reads one line of the file and returns this line as a string, then write a function that receives that string and discard the last characters, and return that string, and so on.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with istringstream off top of my head but I'll look it up now. When searching my textbook pdf, it doesn't appear to be there. I search engine searched it, and I think it's part of objects which we haven't touched on yet- which means it might be "out of bounds" for this assignment. But I do appreciate the feedback and idea because it's something I definitely want to learn. If it's not in my textbook at all, it's probably not okay to use it. The hardest part of courses is not skipping ahead when it solves the problem. But I assume there must be a way to do it without skip ahead.